# Converting Google Ajax Search to a python dictionary

Tags: python, ajax, json, eval

Im trying to write a script that gets google's ajax search results (For example: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=filetype:pdf ) and download every file. Right now I'm stuck trying to convert the response to a python dictionary so its easier to move through.

```
import subprocess
import ast

subprocess.call("curl -G -d 'q=filetype:pdf&v=1.0' http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web  > output",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
file = open('output','r')
contents = file.read()
output_dict = ast.literal_eval(contents)
print output_dict
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ python script.py 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2643    0  2643    0     0  15926      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26696
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 7, in <module>
    output_dict = ast.literal_eval(contents)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

The file looks like:

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch",
                                    "unescapedUrl":"http://www.foundationdb.com/AlphaLicenseAgreement.pdf",
                                             "url":"http://www.foundationdb.com/AlphaLicenseAgreement.pdf",
                                      "visibleUrl":"www.foundationdb.com",
                                        "cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:W7zhFlfbm6UJ:www.foundationdb.com",
                                           "title":"FoundationDB Alpha Software Evaluation License Agreement",
                               "titleNoFormatting":"FoundationDB Alpha Software Evaluation License Agreement",
                                         "content":"FOUNDATIONDB. ALPHA SOFTWARE EVALUATION LICENSE AGREEMENT.   PLEASE READ CAREFULLY THE TERMS OF THIS ALPHA SOFTWARE \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
                                      "fileFormat":"PDF/Adobe Acrobat"
                             },
                             {"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch",
                                    "unescapedUrl":"https://subreg.cz/registration_agreement.pdf",
                                             "url":"https://subreg.cz/registration_agreement.pdf",
                                      "visibleUrl":"subreg.cz",
                                        "cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:ODtRmQsiHD0J:subreg.cz",
                                           "title":"Registration Agreement",
                               "titleNoFormatting":"Registration Agreement",
                                         "content":"Registration Agreement. In order to complete the registration process you must   read and agree to be bound by all terms and conditions herein. TERMS AND \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
                                      "fileFormat":"PDF/Adobe Acrobat"
                             },
                             {"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch",
                                    "unescapedUrl":"http://supportdetails.com/export.pdf",
                                             "url":"http://supportdetails.com/export.pdf",
                                      "visibleUrl":"supportdetails.com",
                                        "cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:h0LvxrTTKzIJ:supportdetails.com",
                                           "title":"Export PDF - Support Details",
                               "titleNoFormatting":"Export PDF - Support Details",
                                         "content":"",
                                      "fileFormat":"PDF/Adobe Acrobat"
                             },
                             {"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch",
                                    "unescapedUrl":"http://www.fws.gov/le/pdf/travelpetbird.pdf",
                                             "url":"http://www.fws.gov/le/pdf/travelpetbird.pdf",
                                      "visibleUrl":"www.fws.gov",
                                        "cacheUrl":"",
                                           "title":"pet bird",
                               "titleNoFormatting":"pet bird",
                                         "content":"U.S. Fish \u0026amp; Wildlife Service. Traveling Abroad with. Your Pet Bird. The Wild Bird   Conservation Act (Act), a significant step in international conservation efforts to \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
                                      "fileFormat":"PDF/Adobe Acrobat"
                             }],
                  "cursor":{"resultCount":"72,800,000",
                                  "pages":[{"start":"0","label":1},
                                           {"start":"4","label":2},
                                           {"start":"8","label":3},
                                           {"start":"12","label":4},
                                           {"start":"16","label":5},
                                           {"start":"20","label":6},
                                           {"start":"24","label":7},
                                           {"start":"28","label":8}],
                            "estimatedResultCount":"72800000",
                            "currentPageIndex":0,
                             "moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den\u0026q\u003dfiletype:pdf","searchResultTime":"0.04"
                           }
                  },
  "responseDetails": null,
  "responseStatus": 200
 }
```

God that took forever to format

Comment: Use one of the online json formatters, e.g. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ allows you to paste json or input a url whence json is loaded from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google returns JSON, so use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) instead of the ast module you are using now.

```
file = open('output','r')
output_dict = json.load(file)
```

You may also want to study the [`urllib2` module](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to load the URL response instead of relying on curl.

Comment: Changing it to json didnt work... Im try to use urllib2 in the mean time but I dont think will help because this is a one time deal and can be dirty coding.

Comment: I can decode your sample as JSON perfectly, not sure why it doesn't work for you..